# Deleting a User from Sudoers File Using a Script

Tags: bash, scripting, centos7, sudoers

I am writing a code script that will delete a user from the Linux CentOS7 box and also remove their sudo permissions.

This is what I have so far:

```
echo -n "Please enter the username you'd like to delete: "
read -r username
passwd --lock $username
userdel -r "$username"
sudo userdel -r "$username" >> /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup
```

I know I may need to move the last line above the last userdel -r line, I definitely know I need some help in making sure that the code is working properly. I have a test box I am running this on so if it blows up, I can recreate it.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly ? What is the output of your script ?

Comment: It will delete the user out of the home directory but when I do

`cat /etc/sudoers.d/sugroup`

It will still show that the user exists in that file.

Answer (score 0):

it sould be enough to use `sudo userdell -r "$username"` , no additional command needed to remove a user and most of its files.

An alternative way to update sudoers content would be using `visudo`, since it protects against many failure modes.

hope this helps.

---

**addition:**
all files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` should have mode 0440 ...

```
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

Comment: Yep, have the sudoers.d/* is set to 0440. that's in another part of the script I didn't add. Thanks though!

Also, while this is true that it should be enough, the client I am writing this for is insisting that the users be removed.

Comment: the user will be removed, otherwise this commands would make no sense. The only thing that will be left over are files out side of `~/`and out side of the `mailspool`. Those files can be removed manually.